# How can i prevent ajax request from reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, file-upload

i have this ajax code which post data to by server side but reloads after upload successuful. i have attached my html code below. kindly help out here, thanks

```
function UploadVid(){
    var file = $("#inputVideo")[0].files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file1", file);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload-video',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",
                uploadProgressHandler,
                true
            );
            xhr.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            console.log(xhr)
            return xhr;
        }
    });
}

//html code
 <div class="col-4 mt-2">
    <label class="col-12">Upload Video File</label>
    <button onclick="$('#inputVideo').trigger('click')"  class="btn btn-primary text-white">Upload</button>
    <input id="inputVideo" onchange="UploadVid(event)" accept="video/*" hidden class="d-none" type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: How is `UploadVid` called?

Comment: Ajax doesn't refresh the page. -- Have you attached the `UploadVid()` function to the submit button of a form?

Comment: i didnt attach to a submit button

Comment: hello thanks for ur time, i just added the html code in the code

Comment: If a button inside a form has no type attribute set, it will automatically be used as `type="submit"`. Add `type="button"` to the button element.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, and improve the quality of your code, remove the inline event handler and attach the event using an unobtrusive method to the `form` element containing the button. From there you can call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to your handler function as an argument to prevent the standard HTTP request caused by the form submission.

In addition, as suggested by @Christopher, add `type="button"` to the button so that it will not submit the form when you click it to select a file to upload.

Try this:

```js
$('#yourForm').on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = $("#inputVideo")[0].files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file1", file);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload-video',
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    xhr: function() {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgressHandler, true);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
      return xhr;
    }
  });
});

$('.upload-btn').on('click', () => {
  $('#inputVideo').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<div class="col-4 mt-2">
  <label class="col-12">Upload Video File</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Upload</button>
  <input type="file" id="inputVideo" hidden class="ulpoad-btn d-none" />
</div>
```